# How fast is the speed of light in vacuum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed-of-light

If we were to travel the speed of light how many times will we be able to orbit the earth in 1 hour? Also how long will it take to make 1 orbit at the speed of light?

Comment: Then calculate the G forces involved and find a suitable material for you spacecraft

Comment: We can't do it, to begin with... light can be sent around the planet in an almost circular path easily with optical fibers, though... at about 60% of the speed of light in vacuum.

Comment: Physics SE is not a homework help site. If you have a question about a homework problem, or any problem of an educational nature, narrow it down to the specific concept that is giving you trouble and ask about that. You can find more information about acceptable homework questions on our [meta site](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) and nowadays [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=speed%20of%20light&rct=j) will inform you, the speed of light is 299,792,458 m/s. Similarly [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius) and [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=earth%20radius&es_th=1&rct=j) put the radius of the Earth at 6,371 km. You can easily do the calculation in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(circumference+of+the+earth)%2F(speed+of+light)) to find a trip around the Earth at the speed of light takes about 133ms. A [similar query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+hour%29*%28speed+of+light%29%2F%28circumference+of+the+earth%29) shows that 26,930 such orbits fit inside an hour.

Or, in other words: show some research effort.

Comment: Ha ha, nice answer, Emilio.